# To split files Under linux Shell

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Input `file.txt`:

```
Start of test case:test1
a
b
c
Date is feb 12
Start of test case:test2
m
n
o
Date is feb 13
Start of test case:test3
x
y
z
Date is feb 14
```

Desired output files

`test1.txt`:

```
Start of test case:test1
a
b
c
Date is feb 12
```

`test2.txt` :

```
Start of test case:test2
m
n
o
Date is feb 13
```

`test3.txt`:

```
Start of test case:test3
x
y
z
Date is feb 14
```

Comment: Out of interest, why did you capitalize the words under and shell but not Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split`:

```
$ split -l 5 file.txt test
```

This will create the three files `testa`, `testb` and `testc`, each with 5 consecutive lines from the file `file.txt`.

Alternatively, a solution in `awk` that writes to a new file whenever a new test case is found:

```
$ awk '/^Start of test case:/ { c++ } { print >sprintf("test%d.txt", c) }' file.txt
```

Comment: Works based on OP Data = always between Start and Date you will have exactly 3 lines; Otherwise is messed up.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou And that's the info that we have available.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Alternative solution in `awk` which works around it added.

Comment: Yes, i was trying to build such a solution . Much better and for sure a future reference. Thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou It separates the sections by counting the lines that matches the pattern. For each match, the value of `c` is increased, which leads to generating a new filename.